# How can I create prefilled realm database in Realm Studio?

Tags: react-native, realm

First of all, excuse me of a newbie question.
I'm absolutely new to Realm.

I'm building a mobile application using React Native and Realm. I've read Realm documentation and describe my schemas with JavaScript.

My application works perfectly with the database (I point path in schemas).
But how can I fill my database with Realm Studio?
When I open created .realm file, I see no data, Realm Studio writes to me that no classes have been created.
Can I import my schemas into Realm Studio?

I also tried to create realm file from zero with Realm Studio. It works perfect, but I can't edit types (names, etc) of fields.

Is there a right way, guys?
Please, help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, no. I just use SQLite )))

Comment: has anyone found a solution to this problem